# fulfillment shopfiy api has no response

Tags: php, curl, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to create fulfillment in shopify app with this code but this has not return me any response

I am geting this response to hit this api

```
Continue
```

my code is:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://key:paswrod@shop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders/#1047/fulfillments.json",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n  \"fulfillment\": {\n    \"location_id\": 39511785531,\n    \"tracking_number\": \"123456789\",\n    \"tracking_urls\": [\n      \"https://shipping.xyz/track.php?num=123456789\",\n      \"https://anothershipper.corp/track.php?code=abc\"\n    ],\n    \"notify_customer\": true\n  }\n}\n",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using order name `#1047` in the request URL. You should use Shopify order ID instead.